# Extended glob does not expand as expected

Tags: bash, glob

I have a bash script named except.sh which is passed a list of files/directories like so:

```
$ ls
a b c d/
$ ./except.sh b c
```

When calling except this way, it should expand to `a d/` i.e. all files/directories except the given names.

Here's how I tried to implement this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# enable extended globbing
shopt -s extglob

# set IFS to | so that $* expands correctly
IFS='|'

printf '%s' !("$*")
```

Given `b c` as parameters, the last line should expand to

```
printf '%s' !(b|c)
```

resulting in `a d` being printed. But to my suprise,

```
abcd
```

is printed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't ls | egrep -v "b|c" do the trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `$*` is in double quotes, which means that its contents will not be treated as a pattern, just like `echo "*"` does not expand the asterisk. Combining the outer pattern with the inner quoted portion automatically escapes the latter, so `!("b|c")` is treated like `!(b\|c)`. Negation of the nonexistent `b|c` file naturally expands to all files in the directory.

An additional problem is that extended globbing is messed up by `IFS` being set to `|`, so you must reset it before expanding the pattern. Therefore, you must do the expansion in two steps: first, calculate the pattern, then reset `IFS` and expand it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# enable extended globbing
shopt -s extglob

# temporarily set IFS to | so that $* expands to part an extended pattern
old_ifs=$IFS
IFS='|'
pattern="!($*)"
IFS=$old_ifs

printf '%s' $pattern
```

Comment: +1 This sounds pretty reasonable. The only thing which I don't get is why setting the IFS to a custom value results in the extended globbing not working anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to the `IFS` variable override (after you override this variable, bash pattern matching behaves odd, example, try `ls -d !(b|c)` before and after setting `IFS`), the following should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# enable extended globbing
shopt -s extglob

PARAMS=$(tr ' ' '|' <<< $*)
printf '%s' !($PARAMS)
```